# I have a problem while installing the Virtual box in Ubuntu 18.04 with dual boot UEFI secure boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, virtualbox, uefi, secure-boot

Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

as root.

If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of the version as well as Secure Boot. I followed the steps:

1. Disable Secure Boot from BIOS settings.
2. Install  VirtualBox 6 (if the problem is with 6.1).